# XSLT Compare Numbers as Strings

Tags: xslt, comparison, string-comparison, numeric-conversion

**Background**

I was recently surprised to notice that XSL was able to intelligently handle numbers; i.e. knowing to treat numbers in text as numeric when performing comparisons (i.e. it understood that `7 < 10` rather than thinking `'10' < '7'`).  In my case that's what I wanted; just not what I'd expected.

Out of curiosity I then tried to force XSLT to compare the numbers as strings (i.e. by using the `string()` function, but with no luck.

**Question**

Is it possible to get XSLT to compare numbers as strings; e.g. so `'10' < '7'`?

**Example**

Source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<element>
  <x>1</x>
  <x>2</x>
  <x>3</x>
  <x>4</x>
  <x>5</x>
  <x>6</x>
  <x>7</x>
  <x>8</x>
  <x>9</x>
  <x>10</x>
</element>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="element">
    <element>

      <AsItComes>
        <xsl:for-each select="./x">
          <xsl:if test="./text() &lt; 7">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."></xsl:copy-of>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </AsItComes>

      <AsNumber>
      <xsl:for-each select="./x">
        <xsl:if test="number(./text()) &lt; 7">
          <xsl:copy-of select="."></xsl:copy-of>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
      </AsNumber>

      <AsString>
        <xsl:for-each select="./x">
          <xsl:if test="string(./text()) &lt; '7'">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."></xsl:copy-of>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </AsString>

    </element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<element>
  <AsItComes>
    <x>1</x>
    <x>2</x>
    <x>3</x>
    <x>4</x>
    <x>5</x>
    <x>6</x>
    <x>10</x>
  </AsItComes>
  <AsNumber>
    <x>1</x>
    <x>2</x>
    <x>3</x>
    <x>4</x>
    <x>5</x>
    <x>6</x>
  </AsNumber>
  <AsString>
    <x>1</x>
    <x>2</x>
    <x>3</x>
    <x>4</x>
    <x>5</x>
    <x>6</x>
    <x>10</x>
  </AsString>
</element>
```

Actual Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<element>
  <AsItComes>
    <x>1</x>
    <x>2</x>
    <x>3</x>
    <x>4</x>
    <x>5</x>
    <x>6</x>
  </AsItComes>
  <AsNumber>
    <x>1</x>
    <x>2</x>
    <x>3</x>
    <x>4</x>
    <x>5</x>
    <x>6</x>
  </AsNumber>
  <AsString>
    <x>1</x>
    <x>2</x>
    <x>3</x>
    <x>4</x>
    <x>5</x>
    <x>6</x>
  </AsString>
</element>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that in **XSLT/XPATH 1.0**, the `string()` value is still evaluated as a number when performing the comparison.

https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans

> When neither object to be compared is a node-set and the operator is
>   <=, <, >= or >, then the objects are compared by converting both
>   objects to numbers and comparing the numbers according to IEEE 754.
>   The < comparison will be true if and only if the first number is less
>   than the second number.

With **XSLT/XPATH 2.0** (and 3.0, and 3.1), you can explicitly set the data type as `xs:string` to ensure that the comparison is performed against strings and not coerced into number values.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                version="2.0">
 <xsl:template match="element">
    <element>
      <AsString>
        <xsl:for-each select="./x">
          <xsl:if test="xs:string(.) &lt; xs:string('7')">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."></xsl:copy-of>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </AsString>
    </element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it is sufficient to compare the value to the string `'7'` (also, you could eliminate the `<xsl:if>` and put your filter in a predicate):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
            version="2.0">
 <xsl:template match="element">
    <element>
      <AsString>
        <xsl:for-each select="./x[. &lt; '7']">
          <xsl:copy-of select="."></xsl:copy-of>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </AsString>
    </element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I agree on the analysis, but for XSLT 2.0 it suffices to use `<xsl:if test=". &lt; '7'">` with a `version="2.0"` stylesheet, suggesting `<xsl:if test="xs:string(.) &lt; xs:string('7')">` I fear people think they have to wrap anything in `xs:string` constructor calls.

Answer (score 2):

if you are going for the first number a work-around could be to just substring the first position.

```
<xsl:if test="substring(./text(), 1, 1) &lt; '7'">
```

returns

```
<AsString>
  <x>1</x>
  <x>2</x>
  <x>3</x>
  <x>4</x>
  <x>5</x>
  <x>6</x>
  <x>10</x>
</AsString>
```

Comment: Thanks @MartinVitek; good workaround.  I'm really interested in whether a full text comparison is possible; though only out of curiosity rather than any necessity / requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in XSLT 1.0 both `'a' > 'b'` and `'b' > 'a'` evaluate as `false`.